# Drawing an undirected graph in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I need to draw some undirected graphs with different coloured vertices. Previously I have been doing this the tedious way, by drawing every vertex as a circle and every edge as a straight line. Is there a way that I can do this easily by using the Bezier curve function? I have tried to do this, but can't work out how to add vertices to my lines!

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to create un-directed graphs with curved edges (since you mention Bezier curves).

I find that the easiest way to draw freestyle graphs is to lay down your vertices as circles (copy & paste for consistent size) and then use the "draw freehand lines" option (pencil icon) to connect the dots. Then you send the circles to the front layer, so the lines look like they start and end at the edges of your circles. If you really want to use Bezier curves instead of free hand, then the method applies just the same. Here's a sample I created using the first method.

[image: graph picture]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. With a bit of practice with the freehand lines, I can see this possibly working.

Comment: For the free hand lines there is also a smoothing slider (from 0 to 100). Setting it to 0 means it draws exactly what your mouse traces out and setting it high lets you draw approximate curves that get nicely smoothed out by an algorithm (that's what I used). Moreover, I think there is a Bezier curve setting that makes it really natural to draw Bezier curves.

Comment: Glad I could help! By the way, if you think it's the correct answer, feel free to accept it as so. :)

Comment: I normally wait a bit on such questions before accepting answers, as you sometimes get alternative answers by doing so. :)

Comment: @Gergely I haven't used either of those but my understanding is that tikz would be an alternative to Inkscape when it comes to drawing SVGs (like the above graph), except tikz can be used entirely within TeX.

Answer (score 0):

So this answer uses an external tool as part of the process, but the end result is still a (good looking) graph inside of inkscape. So for anyone who wants relatively hassle free graphs inside inkscape (or other software) who stumbles across this question, hopefully this will be useful.

There is a (free) tool called the [yEd Graph Editor](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed/download#download) which allows for simple creation of graphs, and after creating a graph you can copy them to the system clipboard (right-click menu) and paste them into inkscape. It requires installing an additional piece of software, but the process can be much faster than creating them manually in inkscape as yEd makes it easy to deal with things like layout, node style, edge style and similar.

This process works with other image software as well, both those that work in bitmap and vector graphics and yEd works with a wide range of graph types.

Comment: Can you include snippets of code, to explain why yED is a good solution? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: There are no code snippets included as the original question (and thus the answer) was not related to specific code. Similar to the currently accepted answer, this answer depends entirely on the use of GUI controls within desktop applications and so code snippets may not be relevant.